# In Pokemon Go when selecting a wild Pokémon does the colored circle have any significance?

Tags: pokemon-go

After the latest update (0.43.3 for Android and 1.13.3 for iOS), selecting a wild Pokémon puts a colored ring around the Pokémon.

[image: Purple ring around Pokémon]

Does this have any significance?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the caption of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ammbE.jpg), it looks like the pink circle shows up once you have clicked on the Pokémon on the map, as a means of letting you know that you've clicked on it.

I just tested it and this seems accurate. It seems like this is to let players know that their click was registered and for which Pokémon (if there are multiple close together).

In addition, from [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5966c6/pink_circle_when_clicking_on_a_wild_pokemon_after/d961miu/),

> if you run from a Pokémon, the pink ring will stay for a little while.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/599q96/ui_update_ring_around_wild_pokemon_when_selected/) is another user reporting that it is simply a UI update:

> When catching wild Pokemon, I noticed a purple ring closing in on the Pokemon that I tapped on. I believe this is a new feature from the newest update. Doesn't seem to have any game play effects.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/598niu/whats_the_purple_ring/) is another:

> So you know which pokemon you are selecting if there are multiple!

Some anecdotal evidence:

[image]

In the image, I'd actually gotten a connection error after tapping the Rattata, and while I waited for something to happen, I tapped the Pidgeotto as well. The pink ring appeared around both, but did nothing. Only after minimizing the app and reopening it to regain connection did tapping on the Rattata again do anything (it started the wild encounter).